# VBA TextBox Input for Searching Records Gives Error 3464 Data type mismatch

Tags: vba

I have an issue using SQL with OpenRecordset command in VBA in order to run through my data. This is my code:

```
Dim SQL as string
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
Dim File as String
Dim i as integer

SQL="SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [Manager no]=" & Forms!Form!TxtManagerNo
Set rs=db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

For i=0 to rs.Recordset-1
   File=File & rs.Fields("Code Nu") 
   rs.MoveNext

Next i

rs.Close
db.Close
```

It gives me Error 3464 as the data type mismatch. However, if I put the `TxtManagerNo` value manually, it works perfectly fine:

```
SQL="SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [Manager no]= '443212'"
```

Could anyone help me with what the issue could be?

Comment: What type of field is `Manager no` ? In your first example the value is not quoted (as you'd expect for a numeric field) but in the second it is quoted (as for a Text-type field)...

Comment: Hi Tim. The TxtManagerNo is taken from a textbox in my form and has a type of Long. However, my table.[Manager no] is type of text. But I have been struggling to transfer the the number to a textformat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your single quotes in your SQL statement indicates that the expected datatype is not an integer or `INT` type.

Either change the data type in the database to INT or modify your SQL statement to:

```
SQL="SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [Manager no]='" & Forms!Form!TxtManagerNo &'"
```

**NOTE**

`Forms!Form!TxtManagerNo` is not being sanitised for anything that may be harmful. If you're using MS Access as the back-end, it's not too bad as it'll not accept two statements as once with a semicolon `;`. If you're using another database though, you might want to consider using parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks Gareth, I now checked the type of data in my table and it seems that my table.[Manager no] is of a type text while my TxtManagerNo is of a type Long.